# Simple project. Two servos are burnt. What's wrong?

Tags: servo

It is a simple project - a focus system for a taken lens and anamorphic adaptor. I have three pots. The first one I use as a manipulator. The second is used to get the position of the continuous rotation servo motor#1. The third pot is used to control the position of the other continuous rotation servo - motor#2.  Motor#1 rotates the taken lens and motor#2 rotates the adaptor.

I use an AOZ1014AI to step down a 7.4V Li-ion battery to 6.5V. First I used two 360-modified JX DC6015(4.8V-6.6V) servos. It worked ok for a minute and then motor#2 burnt. Next I tried Doman servo (4.8-7.2V). This time motor#1 burnt.

Is it ok to connect two servos to one source in parallel?

AOZ1014AI Schematics: [image]

Here is my project schematics:
[image]

And here is AOZ1014 schematics:
[image]

And here is the calculations that I've done in the supplier's xls file:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Have you checked the voltage of the stepped down output? If so, with a multimeter or with a scope? Idle and under load?

Comment: "Is it ok to connect two servos to one source in parallel?" - Yes it is. Would you like to show us your AOZ1014 schematic and some measurements you've taken?

Comment: I've added the schematics. Unfortunately I don't have a scope, just a multimeter.( Perhaps I need just two high voltage servos to exclude the AOZ module.

Comment: The PCB layout isn't a schematic, though it's a fairly simple circuit it would be a lot easier if you included a real schematic.

Comment: Your fundamental flaw is no design specs for all inputs and outputs with fault detection/ avoidance regulation

Comment: Tony, didn't get what you mean. Can you please explain in details.

Comment: I've added all the schematics

Comment: You might be getting overvoltage due to the regenerative energy when you slow or stop your motor.  Your buck can't sink current, and even if it could it may pump up the input cap until the IC fails.  You should monitor the output while slowing and stopping your motors from full speed to see if you get voltage peaks above the abs max rating.

Comment: Thanks I will check it. If so, what should I do?

Comment: If you are getting voltage overshoot due to regen energy you can add enough capacitance to the output of your regulator to absorb the energy or you can use a comparator and resistor to turn on and burn off the energy when the voltage gets above a certain limit (higher than nominal, lower than abs max.)

Comment: It ought to be pretty difficult to burn out a standard RC servo like you are using.  They stand up to abuse pretty well.  You must be getting too much voltage for a fairly long time to kill one of them.

Comment: In the datasheet there is a capacitor in parallel with RFB1. It might have importance for transitory response and missing it might lead to voltage spikes. I don't agree that long overoltage/overload is needed. The servo has a driver inside that can burn instantly.

Comment: Well the cap in parallel with RFB1 has NU letters. Does it mean "not used"? Can I just put a cap on the output? How can I calculate it?

Comment: Another thing is that I'm not a fan of burning off the energy. I've chosen AOZ because it is more efficient comparing to other dc-dc convertors like LM317 for example. I would prefer not to spend my battery on heating the environment.

Comment: Hello! Any ideas?

Comment: I've added 2200uf cap, the voltage according to a multimeter is stable, but motors doesn't work properly.

Comment: @AntonZimin - (a) "*according to a multimeter*" Unfortunately a multimeter is insufficient to fully investigate power-related issues, especially with a switching regulator. I saw your comment that you don't have an 'scope, so it seems we're stuck, as you can't provide the information required :-( (b) I saw where you calculated various component values, but no datasheets / component webpage links were supplied for the *actual* components you chose, so we can't look for problems there. (c) Personally, I have some concerns about the PCB layout, but only 'scope traces would confirm/deny :-(

Comment: Well, here are the datasheets: 

Capacitors (47uf and 22uf):
https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/285/DOC000285639.pdf

 Inductor:
http://datasheetz.com/data/Inductors,%20Coils,%20Chokes/Fixed/495-1799-6-datasheetz.html

 Resistors:
https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/237/DOC000237858.pdf

 Capacitor 2200 pf:
https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/235/DOC000235066.pdf


 Diode:
https://static.chipdip.ru/lib/094/DOC001094093.pdf

Comment: @AntonZimin - Thanks. Although I don't have time for a full review (and I can't run the IC manufacturer's Excel spreadsheet with its macros, at the moment) a couple of points: (a) Your spreadsheet shows you chose a 2.2uH inductor from that datasheet, with 40mΩ DCR - but the datasheet says that inductor has 10mΩ DCR. Why the difference? (b) The 2.2uH inductor part number contains digits "G4222". However your PCB shows the part number contains "G422**3**" which would be a 22uH inductor, not 2.2uH. Which inductor is actually fitted - 2.2uH or 22uH? (c) 'scope still required IMHO :-( Good luck!

Comment: 2.2uH is what I have. 40 or 10 ohm doesn’t make a big difference in the xls file. I’ve ordered a cheap dso168 scope from Ali. Hope it is going to be delivered soon.

Answer (score 1):

While over-voltage is certainly most probable suspect, have you considered checking your code for PWM stability?

If something interrupts pulse train or switches it between two different duty values fast enough the servo might still "work", but will constantly alternate voltage on motor, which would burn it in no time.

One of the tricks I am using when working with linear actuators is to implement hysteresis + low pass filters for all analog inputs in software. Just out of curiosity I'd add debug printout of analog inputs - in these MCUs the ADCs are super-sensitive to noise (and you will be getting a lot of it from servos) without special precautions.

Another one is to make sure you re-configure PWM registers only when necessary (e.g. take into account servo resolution - it is pointless to change duty if servo cannot tell the difference) because in some PWM modes changing frequency produces "glitches" in the output.

UPDATE:

From the comments below: "The more operations I add the more unstable the movements become. The motor starts to move back and forward".

This to me is *very* strong indication that this could be software problem, not hardware. If adding couple operations is enough for motor to start moving it follows that without those operations it still is getting reverse command, only not long enough to *visibly* move.

Basically, you might be commanding it to move back-and-forth as fast as you can, and only when ADC actually changes either "back" or "forth" becomes slightly bigger, enough for servo to change position.

Is there any "humming" coming from servos even when they are seemingly stationary? Especially without physical load.

Comment: Very interesting point. But sorry, what do u mean by “debug printout of analog inputs”? How can I get it? And what is hysteresis and low pass filter in software?

Comment: What I mean is you can modify your code where you are reading ADC inputs and print them out, so you can check them in whatever developing environment your are using. If the values jumping all over the place then you definitely need some kind of filter - either electronic or software.

Comment: The hysteresis filter compares incoming values and only allows new values through if there were several (strength of a filter) subsequent changes in same direction. The low pass filter combines part of previous value with part of incoming data to get a new value.

Comment: Now I see. Yes, there is a small oscillation +-1, but I think I catch it up by decreasing a resolution twice. But thank you I will check it again.

Comment: The thing is that Arduino seems to bit a bit slow for all this kind of filters. The more operations I add the more unstable the movements become. The motor starts to move back and forward because it looses the pot’s value where it had to stop.

Comment: Interesting... The Arduino can easily handle ten times more tasks than this. Do you by any chance generate PWM by some kind of pulseout commands? Or even with delays? If you do, this is the worst possible approach to the task. The MCU has hardware PWM channels. Once programmed they send out pulses by themselves while program is free to do something else.

Comment: @SamGibson Thanks for the hint, I'll keep that in mind. Although _your_ comment should have done the trick this time.